# Combinatorial proof using Pascal's identity

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given Pascal's identity
$$\binom nr=\binom{n-1}r+\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$
how would you prove this?
$$x\binom{x-1}{y-1}=y\binom xy$$
I've been struggling with this problem for forever at this point, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Directly, $$\binom xy=\dfrac xy\cdot\dfrac{(x-1)!}{(y-1)!\cdot\{x-1-(y-1)\}!}=\dfrac xy\binom{x-1}{y-1}$$

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that we can't use algebra - the proof should be combinatorial

Answer (score 1):

Both sides count the number of committees of size $y$ with one distinguished member.  There are two ways to do that.

First, we can form a committee of size $y$ and then select the distinguished member from those $y$ people. Therefore, we have $\binom{x}{y}y$ ways to do that.

On the other hand, we can start selecting the distinguished member (there are $x$ ways to do that). Afterwards, we choose $y-1$ from the remaining $x-1$ people. This leads to $x\binom{x-1}{y-1}$ committees.